# How to add my textareas

Tags: java, swing, double, converters, jtextarea

So, im making a program for calculating water catchment. And I have 2 textareas(JFrame) and I need to convert them to a double, so, basically I want to do this!

```
double a = textarea1;
double b = textarea2;  // textarea1 and textarea2 are JTextArea's
double c = a * b * 0.0632
```

How to convert `JTextArea` to double *or* how to make a double with the same value as what the user put in the `JTextArea`?

Comment: If the values are numeric, use a `JSpinner` with a [`SpinnerNumberModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SpinnerNumberModel.html).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need this:-

```
double a = Double.parseDouble(textarea1.getText());
```

Comment: YAY thank you so much, you are a pro sir!                                                                 But, how do I access that varible from my other method! Thanks

Comment: Either declare your variable in global scope, to access it in other methods, or else, return that variable, for this method, to whichever method wanting to use that value.

Comment: +1 to the answer :-), though, there is no such thing as having global scope in Java IMHO. One can have that variable be declared as an `Instance Variable` and put a `getter` method to retrieve it's value.